# Can't add a property wrapper for Realm object

Tags: swift, realm

I'm trying to add a handy property wrapper for my optional properties for avoiding writing `age.value = 2`.

```swift
@propertyWrapper
class RealmOptionalWrapper<T: RealmOptionalType> {

    let _wrappedValue = RealmOptional<T>()

    var wrappedValue: T? {
        get {
            _wrappedValue.value
        }
        set {
            _wrappedValue.value = newValue
        }
    }
}

@objcMembers
class Test: Object {
    @RealmOptionalWrapper
    var age: Int?
}
```

But this code fails at runtime with the following error:

> No properties are defined for 'Test'. Did you remember to mark them
> with '@objc' in your model?

Are there any workarounds for this?

Comment: Using `let age = RealmOptional<Int>()` is a good idea. Also, Test has no managed Realm properties; keep in mind that even with @objcMembers, you still need to define managed properties with dynamic, unless it's defined as optional as previously mentioned.

Comment: And now that I think about, you may have additional issues with other property types; a String for example `@objc dynamic var value: String? = nil` is not defined in the same way as an Int is `let value = RealmOptional<Int>()`. Just thinking out loud here.

Comment: @Jay Thanks for pointing it out and I understand the pitfalls so that I plan to use different wrappers. Just for the question decided to simplify the example.